# why std::cin doesn't give error on "char"

Tags: c++, inputstream, cin

Here is a small code:

```
char a;
while(std::cin >> a) {
    std::cout << a << " is pressed\n";
}
```

When I type in "w", i get "w is pressed".
When I type in "www", i get "w is pressed" 3 times in a row.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `while (std::cin >> a)`.

Comment: Why do you expect it to give an error?

Comment: because its a string. But then I understand that it kind of does `std::cin >> a >> a >> a;`. How can I change that?

Comment: **WHAT** do you want to achieve/expect `std::cin` to behave?? This might turn out to be different from reality (i.e. how `std::istream` actually behaves) ...

Answer (score 4):

When you use std::cin to read a char variable it reads one character at a time. That is why you get 3 iterations in the while loop for input www.

Comment: @Gasim don't use a while if you just want one input

Comment: well, then I should use string with this knowing it will works, right?

Comment: @Gasim _'well, then I should use string ...'_ **No!** Looks like,  you'll want to process key-pressed events, instead of processing streamed input (from keyboard, file, socket connection, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

There is a `queue` of inputs. if you entered too much, your input waits in patient...

Comment: how can I clear the queue them? right after the first character then

Comment: no luck; i just inputted std::string to cin and got the character by string.at(0)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the answer is on the first line of your code.

```
char a;
```

Variable `a` is a single `char`, an 8-bit value typically used to store a code representing a display character. If the display is ASCII, then (value) 0 = no character, (value) 32 = space, value 48 = (character) '0', etc.

`std::cin` is an instance of class `std::istream`, it has various members and operator overloads to deal with different types. In the case of a `char`, you are calling

```
std::istream::operator(char)
```

Which reads one `char`, exactly one, from the input stream and returns.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```